# (failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on large file upload php

Tags: php, html, ajax

**Html Code:**

```html
<form id="fileuploadform" method="post" name="fileuploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label class="control-label font-blue-madison bold">Select the File To Upload:</label>
                    <input type="File" name="test" id="testfile">
                    <input id="sss" type="button" value ="sss" name="test_uploa_form">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**AJAX CALL:**

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sss').click(function(){
            var file_data = $('#testfile').prop('files')[0]; 
            var form_data = new FormData();                  
            form_data.append('file', file_data);
            console.log(file_data);

            $.ajax({
                url: '../controllers/data_load_ajax.php?action=uploadfile',
                dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'post',
                success: function(php_script_response){
                    alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I am facing issues while uploading large files on the server using ajax call. It will not reach uploading code but before it reaches ajax function it always throws an error like **"(failed)net:: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"** what should be the reason behind?

Comment: Please check your error logs on the server first, they can give an indication. If you are running a (cheaper) shared webhost, it might be possible they limited the resources/limits.

Comment: Actually it's an AWS server, not cheaper one and the problem is ajax call is not completing but before it is giving error after taking  27.9 seconds all the time when I upload a file of 300000 records. Do you have any other suggestions?